# Detect a remote desktop connection from a service at logon (W7/32)

Tags: c#, windows, service, rdp

I know (and it works) that in C#, this property tells me if the current session is a RDP one:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession
```

Now, I have a service that receives logon/logoff and lock/unlock events, and I need a way to tell this service if the session being started is rdp or local.

Problem: the service runs as SYSTEM user, and the property above always returns false (I think because SYSTEM is always considered a local connected user)

I've tried to search in the register for the Volatile Environment subkey to check if there is the subkey that identify the RDP Session Name: this works in lock/unlock handler, but in the logon handler the subkey doesn't exists yet (subkey is created after login completes).

Any idea about how to work around this problem?

While a wait for the key creation for a limited amount of time works, I would like a less "kludgy" way to do it.

Comment: It's not because the service is running from SYSTEM but simply because it is a service.  All services run in session 0, which is local by definition.  What information about the new logon are you currently getting?  See here for the API functions available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The information that I have on the new logon are those that I can read from the Volatile Environment, and nothing else. And every query that I can do on the WTS subsystem for the "current" session, as you said, says that the connection is local so I can't get info from them. I think I'll try to find a way to enumerate *all* the WTS sessions and extract the information from each one. On our machines there is an enforced limit of just one concurrent RDP session, so I expect to find at most one session with rdp data. A QuerySessionInfos on that session should give me the data I need... (I hope)

Comment: If you're being informed of the logon via the SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE event, the WTSSESSION_NOTIFICATION structure includes the session ID.  You only need to query that particular session.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Great! Tomorrow I'll change the code to do what you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect whether a session is a local or remote session by calling [WTSQuerySessionInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `WTSInfoClass` parameter set to `WTSClientProtocolType`. If you'd prefer to avoid the P/Invokes, you can use the [Cassia library](https://code.google.com/p/cassia/): `new TerminalServicesManager().GetLocalServer().GetSession(sessionId).ClientProtocolType`.

Caveats: This won't help you when processing session logoff messages because you will not (reliably) be able to fetch information about the session, since it's in the process of being destroyed (but that seems relatively easy to work around). Also, the `ClientProtocolType` Cassia property mentioned above has not yet been released, but you can grab a trunk build from the [build server](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project51) by logging in as a guest and using the artifacts link.

Comment: I didn't knew that library... very very interesting, thanks!. About the logoff, not a problem, because the service needs to verify the protocol type only at logon.